# поменять местами в матрице наибольшие элементы в первом и последнем столбце

Tags: массивы, numpy, матрицы, индексы

нужно сформировать целочисленную матрицу А[n,m] с помощью генератора случайных чисел (random). в матрице поменять местами наибольшие элементы в первом и последнем столбцах.
вычислить значение коэффициента корреляции между элементами первого и последнего столбца.

была попытка через индексы менять местами элементы, но не получилось

```
import numpy as np
import random
a=np.random.random((4,4))
if a[0][i]>a[3][i]:
    a[0][i], a[3][i]==a[3][i],a[0][i]
ptint(a)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Все ваши попытки должны быть приведены прямо в вопросе.

Comment: Откуда взялась `i` - это же переменная цикла, да? А где он, этот цикл? Ну и у вас `==` вместо `=`, поэтому ошибка.